# XNA - sound in update method

Tags: xna

I am trying to play a sound when the gameState changes

For example I am in the Main menu, I click on Instructions and it plays a sound. I click back button it plays the same sound again.

I am having a lot of trouble implementing this!

```
    case GameState.MainMenu:
                if (PlayButton.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.Levels;
                menuSoundPlayOnce = true;
                PlayButton.Update(mouse);
                if (instructionsButton.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.Instructions;
                instructionsButton.Update(mouse);
                if (quitButton.isClicked == true)
                Exit();
                quitButton.Update(mouse);
                break;


case GameState.Instructions:
                if (backButton.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;
                backButton.Update(mouse);
                if (!menuToMenuSoundPlayOnce)
                {
                    menuToMenuSound.Play();
                }
                menuToMenuSoundPlayOnce = true;
                break;
```

I got the sound to only play once using the code

```
if (!menuToMenuSoundPlayOnce)
                {
                    menuToMenuSound.Play();
                }
                menuToMenuSoundPlayOnce = true;
```

But it plays once and of course menuToMenuSoundPlaceOnce is set to false.
If I change this to stay as false, it just plays the sound over and over.

I can't seem to find anywhere online about this.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
//Get a instance of the sound effect -- do this once only
SoundEffectInstance menuSoundInstance = menuToMenuSound.CreateInstance();


//Play the sound during update, if the sound is not already playing
if (menuSoundInstance.State == SoundState.Stopped)
{
    menuToMenuSound.Play();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply,

I have tried adding this, but still the sound continues to play constantly.

I just want it ones per gameState but can't seem to get it

Comment: Make sure you only instantiate your SoundEffectInstance once, outside of your Update() method.  You would typically create this object at the class level, and load it during your LoadContent()